# Fallout: New Vegas not playing

Tags: xbox-360, technical-issues, fallout-new-vegas

A friend gave me *Fallout: New Vegas* for Xbox 360, but it didn't come with a case and the disc was scratched up. I played it for a while and got pretty far, then it just froze up. I bought a new disc of the same game, but when I put it in it says "reading," and then tells me to open the tray.

What's happening, and what should I do to fix it?

Comment: Do other games still work fine on the console?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on whether you can play other games, This sounds to me like the old disk was that badly damaged, that it may have damaged the eye on the disk drive.

There are cleaning kits you can acquire for the disk reader eye in the disk tray. I would possibly inquire down that route.

Answer (score 0):

This is either a system bug with your system or a file corruption that is breaking the program startup. Try deleting your save and game data.